# $this->getUser()->isAdmin() VS $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')

Tags: symfony

I have to check if a user is an "admin" many times in my application.

I wonder which is the best way in terms of performance.

There are at least two (inside a controller):

```
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

$this->getUser()->isAdmin();
```

Users is an ORM class which maps a mysql table:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default"=0})
     */
    private $isAdmin = 0;

    // [...]

    public function isAdmin(){
        return $this->isAdmin;
    }

    // [...]

    public function getRoles()
    {
        if($this->isAdmin()) {
            return ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'];
        } else {
            return ['ROLE_USER'];
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the `getUser()->isAdmin()` should be faster, unless the security system caches the roles in some ways...

EDIT: I ended up using `$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');` since it's shorter to type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of performance it depence. If performance is a important factor of your application you should profile it with blackfire. If your database is clustered and spread around the world, the method with the authorization_checker will be faster. If your DIC is to big, and your database lives on the same server, the isAdmin() method might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've never use `getUser()` to read the role.

Use the SecurityContext, or an implementation of AccessDecisionManager instead, e.g.

`$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');`